# syntax error in replace expression for subject making in access

Tags: forms, ms-access, replace, expression

i am very new to expressions in access,

In my access data base i need to parse some fields into subject of the outlook when send mail button clicked in the form , for this i am using replace expression as below :

```
=Replace(Replace("Rework |1: Reason|2:Drawing Number|3","|1",Nz([Order_Number],"")),"|2",Nz([Reason_for_rework],"")),"|3",Nz([Drawing_Or_Mat_Number],""))
```

but for this i am getting error as :

```
"the 'emaildatabaseobject' macro action has an invalid value for the 'subject' argument
```

Kindly help me how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You syntax is completely off. You may have *Choose* in mind:

```vb
=Choose(YourCategoryID,Nz([Order_Number],""),Nz([Reason_for_rework],""),Nz([Drawing_Or_Mat_Number],""))
```

Comment: yes' as i said i am still learning this , but the data in these fields has to come in subject field of my outlook hence i selected "Replace"(as choose will not get my data), can you please correct my syntax in replace so that it can take 3 fields.Thank you.

Comment: You can't change the behaviour of Replace. Please study the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/replace-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Comment: Okay thank you , i corrected the syntax and now it is working :  =Replace(Replace(Replace("Please note that there is a high qty of rework found in above order where inspected qty is:|1  Rework qty is: |2  And % is:|3 ","|1",Nz([Inspected_Qty],"")),"|2",Nz([Rework_Qty],"")),"|3",Nz([Rework_Percentage],""))